# React OnClick={function() { } } Not Doing Anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, jsx

This is what my code looks like:

```
function Header() {
    const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    let buttonHit = false;

    const handleAuth = () =>
    {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => 
        {
            if (authUser)
            {
                console.log("sume else");
                auth.signOut();
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("sum");
                navigate('/Login');
            }  
        });
    }

    return (
        <Navbar className="navbar" bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
                <Link className="navbar-brand" to='/'><Navbar.Brand>Scythe's Sweet Treats</Navbar.Brand></Link>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="main-navbar" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="main-navbar">
                    <Nav className="mr-auto">
                        <Link to='/' className="nav-links">Home</Link>
                        <Link to='/Products' className="nav-links">Products</Link>
                        <Link to='/About' className="nav-links">About</Link>
                        <Link to='/Gallery' className="nav-links">Gallery</Link>
                        <Link to='/ContactUs' className="nav-links">Contact Us</Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav className="ms-auto">
                        {(user) ? user.uid === 'TirT8syQ6jdbaFPTC0So2HLlsie2' ? <Link className="nav-links" to='/Admin'>Admin</Link> : <Link to='#' className="d-none"></Link> : null}
                        <Link className='nav-links' to='#'>Hello, {!user ? 'Guest': user.email}</Link>
                        <Link onclick={() => handleAuth()} to="#" className="nav-links">{user ? 'Sign Out' : 'Sign In'}</Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

I've been having the issue that when I login the onclick is fired immediately and logs the user out, so I changed it because I read a stackOverflow with the same problem. But changing it to {function() {handleAuth()} } or {() => {handleAuth()}} or {() => handleAuth()}

Comment: `onclick={() => handleAuth()}` will work or `onclick={handleAuth}`. But your code suggests you've solved that problem.

Comment: I'm closing this now because I did find a work around, but the issue was the when i did onClick={handleAuth} it would trigger as soon as the page loads and logout the user, but when i did onClick={() => handleAuth()} it didn't do anything, not even console.logs would show up. My work around ended up being using a link and a to="loginRedirect" to make a page that checks if there is a user and handles signin/signout on its own. But with that I was having the same issue where it would logout the user immediately. I ended up using window.location.replace instead of useNavigate.

Comment: Essentially navigate was making it still consider the redirect page once it was on the login page. Like all the login page was supposed to do was signin, and redirect to homepage. But it would act like it went back to the redirect page and checked again and signed the user out and would refresh a bunch. It was just strange. Only happened on production server too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this now because I did find a work around, but the issue was the when i did onClick={handleAuth} it would trigger as soon as the page loads and logout the user, but when i did onClick={() => handleAuth()} it didn't do anything, not even console.logs would show up. My work around ended up being using a link and a to="loginRedirect" to make a page that checks if there is a user and handles signin/signout on its own. But with that I was having the same issue where it would logout the user immediately. I ended up using window.location.replace instead of useNavigate for this reason. Read the other comment to see why navigate didn't work.

Edit: Forgot you can't just close a question on stackoverflow lmao